# LINQ Query returns duplicates

Tags: json, linq

I have folowing code which should return selected data to my view, but i have issue with duplicate from reas.CarType...

This is a code:

```
public JsonResult GetRegister()
        {
            using (FamilyRegisterContext db = new FamilyRegisterContext())
            {              

                var familyRegistarData = (from fag in db.FamiliyGroups
                                          from reas in db.CarsAndRealEstate

                                             where (fag.GroupedFamilyId == reas.GroupedFamilyId)

                                          select new
                                          {
                                              fag.FamilyGroupid,

                                              fag.FamilyName,
                                              fag.FamilyMemberName,
                                              fag.Year,
                                              fag.BankName,
                                              fag.Amount,
                                              reas.CarType,
                                              reas.ProductionYear,
                                              reas.RegistrationNumber,
                                              reas.Address,
                                              reas.Other
                                          }).ToList().Distinct();

    var distinct = familyRegistarData.GroupBy(s =>  s.FamilyMemberName).Select(y => y.First());

return new JsonResult { Data = distinct, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };

            }

        }[enter image description here][1]
```

Before i added a GroupBy i have same issue with FamilyMemberName but now this is solved.. The only problem i have now is as said duplicate from CarType...

Please help im stuck :)

"Updates"

```
 This is my angular view presentation
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/juCwZ.png
```

And this is a table relationship
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=35ch4t2&s=9#.Vo6pX4bR9aQ

This is data in my tables 
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2ev6xzb&s=9#.Vo6s44bR9aQ

As i can see there a CarType and Address which are duplicates..

Comment: What is the issue with duplicate, you do not need Duplicates or are you getting an error ?

Comment: You're doing a cross-join relating all families to all car types.  Is there not some sort of relationship between the two?  If you just want distinct combinations add `CarType` to your `GroupBy`.

Comment: Hi thnx for your answer , i was  used  a joins before without success , i doing  something  wrong but i cant see it  :(

See updates , have some  links where you can see  relationships  in the  DB and data view...

Comment: Hi Agalo.. nope there  is  no errors my jsonresult sending data to view  without a problems, the issue is a duplicate  carType and Address..

Answer (score 0):

i think the following code should do what you are trying to achieve :

```
 var distinct = familyRegistarData
                   .GroupBy(s => new { s.FamilyMemberName, s.CarType })
                   .Select(y => y.First());
```

Comment: Hi Proviste .. thnx for your answer , i have used a same code before but without success ..